# How to trace and resolve a theme problem such as flickering links in WordPress?

Tags: themes, css, html

When I hover the mouse/cursor over any link on my website the link flickers and it takes some time for the link to be active.

You can see this here `https://www.ff-almoshof.de` when you hover over any link on images and text.

I have tried to analyze the code of my theme but couldn't find anything obviously connected to the problem.

Have you any idea how I could solve this?

Comment: It's usually best to contact the theme author directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still interested to look for the reason, here is the CSS code that cause the flickering (which is a CSS related issue).

In the theme's style.css

```
  a:focus, a:hover {
    /* ... */
    animation-name: fadeIn; /* <=== this cause the flickering, just comment it out or use another CSS to override this such as animation-name: none; */
    /* ... */
  }
```

Like @WebElaine mentions, generally if theme has problem, you may consider

- contact the author
- sometimes, maybe there is chance that you might need to overcome the problem immediately before author updating the theme, you may consider to add your own override. You could do it by using [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and create your own CSS file.

Comment: Thank you! I overwridden the animation-name and it works great.

Comment: It is nice to know that can help. I love CSS. Happy coding!